# JQuery - select input by "special" name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select radio input by its name. I know that to do so i have to use something like:

```
    $('input[type=radio][name=myInputName]')
```

The problem is that my input name has '[]' in it, so this is causing an error.
here is the error i got:

```
    Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=radio][name=fields[field_5a65c638349f9]]...
```

Comment: Wrap it in single quotes: `$("input[type=radio][name='myInputName[]']")`

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Comment: @Badr If you have it like this `$('input[type=radio][name=fields[field_5a65c638349f9]]')` then you need to escape the `[]` like this `$('input[type=radio][name=fields\\[field_5a65c638349f9\\]]')`

Comment: can't you use just the name to simplify? `$("[name='myInputName']")`

Comment: @CalvinNunes - It's probably generated html.

Comment: @CalvinNunes You're right, that would be better.